# identify the dead iscsi paths in ESXi

Tags: storage, vmware, iscsi

added 8 static discovery to the VMware iscsi s/w adapter

4 IPs are from one storage server which is down now, when i do the rescan in this state it take hell lot of time. once i remove those 4 IPs ( dead paths ) rescan is working faster

is there a way to identify the iscsi path( IP:PORT IQN) is dead or iscsi session is established with vCenter

tried esxcli session list, no luck

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, if you add target IPs into the *static* list and those IPs are not available due to dead server, the iscsid on ESXi side will try to establish connection to those IPs only once (as a result of rescan) and after connection fails, it won't try again and you will not see the sessions or connections via esxcli commands like these

```
esxcli iscsi session list
esxcli iscsi session connection list
```

You can look into /var/log/syslog.log and run tcpdump-uw to confirm that. Because sessions/connections physically do not exists, I don't think there is a direct way to get them.

One possible workaround is to run this command

```
esxcli iscsi session connection list | grep -e State -e RemoteAddress
```

to get list of targets to which you have working connections. Then you can extract those IPs from the static list of targets associated with iSCSI adapter to get the list of IPs for which you don't have established connections.